# Do prone creatures provide cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, cover

So in RAW, having a creature between the attacker and a target grants the target half cover, but I'm a grappler that likes to shove down my victims while grappling. Do I still get the cover bonus for having a creature between us if he's prone in RAW? I'm worried that my DM will overrule because it doesn't make physical sense if he's prone to also provide cover.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## A creature *might* provide cover. A prone creature probably won't.

Here are the rules for half cover:

> A target with **half cover** has a +2 bonus to AC and Dexterity saving throws. ***A target has half cover if an obstacle blocks at least half of its body.*** The obstacle might be a low wall, a large piece of furniture, a narrow tree trunk, or a creature, whether that creature is an enemy or a friend.

(Emphasis mine, PHB, p. 196).

So the rules as written aren't that a creature between the attacker and target always grants half cover; it's that such a creature *can* grant half cover.

A prone creature probably doesn't block at least half of a standing character's body, and so it wouldn't provide half cover. Similarly, a standing halfling doesn't provide cover for a half-orc standing behind it.